# While Loop and Pandas Iterrows

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop, dataframe

I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 10 and the Spyder Python IDE

I am trying to calculate posterior conditional probabilities of reaching any node in a network from any other node. The network is defined by a `dataframe` where each row is a directional connection (called `edge` in graph theory) between `fld1` and `fld2`, and `value` is the probability of moving from `fld1` to `fld2`.

In order to calculate the probabilities I need to loop through the `dataframe`. I am using `iterrows` from `pandas` but I am also implementing a `while loop` for capturing indirect paths from one node to another.

My code is below. My question is, is my code correct in the fact that I can use `pandas iterrows` and a `while loop`?

```
import pandas as pd
#from itertools import combinations
from itertools import permutations    
df = pd.DataFrame({'fld1': ['apple', 'apple', 'bear','bear','car','car','car','dee','dee','eagle','eagle']
            ,  'fld2': ['bear', 'car', 'car','eagle','bear','dee','eagle','eagle','foo','dee','foo']
            , 'value': [.3,.3,.2,.1,.3,.3,.2,.4,.1,.3,.2]})

## define global objects

#starter value holders
og_fld1_val = []
og_fld2_val = []
og_r_val = []

#df of already checked r_vals
dnc_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['fld1','fld2','distance'])

##df of all r_vals to find
flds = pd.Series(df.fld1.unique())
flds = pd.Series(flds.append(pd.Series(df.fld2.unique())).unique())

combos = []
for L in range(0, len(flds)+1):
  for subset in permutations(flds, L):
      if len(subset) == 2:
        combos.append(subset)
rel_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data = combos, columns = ['fld1','fld2'])
####for all rows of df

#for each fld1-fld2 relationship in df 
# aka (each edge in the network, starting with a-b) 
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    #take row 1 info for fld1 and fld2 seperately
    og_fld1_val = df.fld1[index]
    og_fld2_val = df.fld2[index]
    og_r_val = df.value[index]

    #add info to do not try again list
    dnc_df.set_value(index, 'fld1', og_fld1_val)
    dnc_df.set_value(index, 'fld2', og_fld2_val)

    #variable value holders
    #fld1_val = []
    #fld2_val = []
    #r_val = []

    ###fld1 has been established now for each path from fld1 outwards 
    for index, row in df.loc[df.fld1 == og_fld1_val].iterrows():

        #see next connection that is not the terminal node                       
        while og_fld2_val <> df.loc[df.fld1 == og_fld1_val].fld2[index]:

           #capture relationship between previous node and next node
           try:
               r_val
           except:
               r_val = df.loc[df.fld1 == og_fld1_val].value[index]
           else:
               r_val = r_val * df.loc[df.fld1 == og_fld1_val].value[index]

           #if r_val in globals():
            #   r_val = r_val * df.loc[df.fld1 == og_fld1_val].value[index]
           #else:
            #   r_val = df.loc[df.fld1 == og_fld1_val].value[index]

           if r_val < 0.001:  
               continue
```

My goal is to create the `r_val` column so that `df` becomes `df2`. In reality my dataset is massive (500K+ rows) and this is just a sample dataset.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'fld1': ['apple', 'apple', 'bear','bear','car','car','car','dee','dee','eagle','eagle']
            ,  'fld2': ['bear', 'car', 'car','eagle','bear','dee','eagle','eagle','foo','dee','foo']
            , 'value': [.3,.3,.2,.1,.3,.3,.2,.4,.1,.3,.2]
            , 'r_val': [.39,.36,.2,.164,.3,.369,.35,.4,.18,.3,.23]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'fld1': ['apple', 'apple', 'bear','bear','car','car','car','dee','dee','eagle','eagle']
        ,  'fld2': ['bear', 'car', 'car','eagle','bear','dee','eagle','eagle','foo','dee','foo']
        , 'value': [.3,.3,.2,.1,.3,.3,.2,.4,.1,.3,.2]})
gsums = df.groupby("fld1").sum()  # source group sums
df.set_index("fld1", inplace=True)  # set index to source column
df["sums"] = gsums  # new column sums in dataframe for next operation
df["rval"] = df["value"] / df["sums"]  # divide the columns
df.drop("sums", axis=1, inplace=True)  # drop the sums column
df.reset_index(inplace=True)  # reset index to the original
```

But, it would have be easier if you had your transition likelihoods/probabilities stored in an n-by-n frame. Then you could do for example:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import rand
vars = ("fld1", "fld2", "fld3")
n = len(vars)
df = pd.DataFrame(rand(n, n), index=vars, columns=vars)
dfprobs = df/df.sum(axis=0)  # divide by sum of rows, or axis=1 to divide by sum of columns
```

Also for python graphs I recommend looking on igraph and networkx.

Comment: I appreciate the answer.I have used both networkx and igraph and surprisingly neither module has what I am looking for. Bayespy seems like it might have something close but I am running on Windows. The problem with `[groupby][1]` is that I would have to do that iteratively for each connection, which kind of gets me back to my original issue.

Comment: See update. No need to be done iteratively, only use dataframe operations :). Still the n-by-n dataframe might be a more suitable representation for transitions (they are usually called transition matrices for a reason ;) and would make thing much simpler.

Comment: Thank you for the update! I have done some brief studying of Transition Matrices and MCMC and it seems that the probability of reaching a node only depends on the previous node. Therefore this would not be able to capture the indirect relationship between "apple" and "foo" because they are not directly connected. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes that's the Markovian assumption in brief. And yes using chain rule you can compute the transition of indirect linkage between apple and foo, and due to the markovian assumption it is basically the product of the individual transitions between apple and foo. If the reply helps and answers your question please don't forget to mark it as such and up vote it for future generations:).